# How to add an ID variable in the row annotations using "ComplexHeatmap" package in R?

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I've created a basic heatmap where the columns correspond to time points and the rows each represent an individual. In my dataset I have an ID variable and I would like it to show up in the row annotations so that I can clearly see which rows in the heatmap correspond to which individual. Take a look at the image attached below.

[image]

I would simply like individual IDs to show up on the left, between the dendogram and the heatmap.

So far I have created a matrix with my CSV file

`mymatrix<-as.matrix(mydata[ ,c(2:9)]`

And run the heatmap function while forcing it to cluster only on rows

`Heatmap(mymatrix,cluster_columns = FALSE)`

Also, I would like to create a seperate column that shows up on the right side of the heatmap that would represent an individual's revenue but that doesn't influence the clustering. With dark colors representing an individual with large revenue and light colors one with weak revenue.

Thank you for any help provided!

Comment: check the `heatmap.3` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heatmap3/vignettes/vignette.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Assume your "id" is encoded as `id` and "revenue" as `revenue`. Both are vectors. You can make the heatmap as follows:

```
revenue_col = c("large" = "black", "weak" = "grey")
library(ComplexHeatmap)
ht_list = rowAnnotation(id = row_anno_text(id, just = "right"), 
        width = max_text_width(id)) + 
    Heatmap(mymatrix, name = "mymatrix", cluster_columns = FALSE) + 
    Heatmap(revenue, col = revenue_col, width = unit(5, "mm")
ht_list
```

To put the dendrogram on the most left:

```
draw(ht_list, row_dend_side = "left")
```